# What size of batches can I produce with a 12L pot(biab)?

Tags: equipment, boil, biab

I'm thinking about moving from extract with grains brewing to all grain brewing, instead of buying a bigger pot I'm thinking about using the same one I used for extract and downsize my butch (which actually solves a bunch of other problems for me). What size of batches can I produce with a 12L pot (actually an electric urn) doing BIAB in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably 1.5 to 2 gal batches, I used BIAB in a 2.5 gal bucket, to make 1 gal batches for test.